# Proof of "Eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvalues are linearly independent."

Tags: linear-algebra

"Eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvalues are linearly independent."

My professor told us this during a lecture, but gave no proof or explanation.

Answer (score 11):

Suppose that $Av=\lambda v$ and $Aw=\mu w$, $v,w\not=0$.

Assume $v,w$ are linearly dependent, then $v=c\cdot w$ for some scalar $c\not=0$. Then

$$\lambda v=Av=cAw=c \mu w = \mu v$$

That is, $\lambda=\mu$.

Comment: You surely mean dependent?

Comment: @DanielFischer, alex Thank you!

Comment: The theorem is more general then this. If you have $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_m$ as distinct eigenvalues and $v_1,\ldots,v_m$ be corresponding eigenvectors, then $v_1,\ldots,v_m$ are linearly independent.

Comment: @caffeinemachine should be obvious how to generalize the technique in the answer...

Comment: @gt6989b I disagree but may be that's just me.

Comment: @caffeinemachine [here's one way](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29371/how-to-prove-that-eigenvectors-from-different-eigenvalues-are-linearly-independe/29399#29399) to do so.  I agree that there doesn't seem to be a particularly "obvious" approach.

Comment: @caffeinemachine Maybe I don't understand something. If you let $v_1$ be a linear combination of the others, i.e.
$$v_1 = \sum_{k=2}^m c_k v_k$$
then
$$\sum_{k=2}^m c_k \lambda_k v_k
  = A \sum_{k=2}^m c_k v_k
  = A v_1
  = \lambda_1 v_1
  = \lambda_1 \sum_{k=2}^m c_k v_k
  = \sum_{k=2}^m \lambda_1 c_k v_k$$
so
$$\sum_{k=2}^m \lambda_1 c_k v_k = \sum_{k=2}^m c_k \lambda_k v_k$$
which implies that $\lambda_1 c_k = c_k \lambda_k$ for all $k$, since $v_k$ are linearly independent, and so either $c_k \equiv 0$ or $\lambda_1 = \lambda_k \quad \forall k$.

Comment: @gt6989b You are right. That does make it seem obvious. The way I did it was quite convoluted compared to this.

Comment: @gt6989b two things:

a) I don't get how you go from $\Sigma c_k v_k \lambda_k$ to $A \Sigma c_k v_k$. Can you explain that?
b) What is the "conclusion", I don't understand how this proves it.

Comment: @jacob $v_k \lambda_k = A v_k$ and so
$$\sum c_k v_k \lambda_k = \sum c_k A v_k = \sum A c_k v_k = A \sum c_k v_k$$
since matrix multiplication commutes with constant multiplication.

Comment: @jacob If all $c_k \equiv 0$, then $v_1 = \vec{0}$, so this cannot happen. Alternatively, if $\lambda_1 = \lambda_k \forall k$, then the eigenvectors $v_k$ turn out to correspond to the same eigenvalue.

Comment: Oh wow, this is nicer than the usual induction proof.

Comment: Brilliant Proof!