# Can I change an axiom to something that is logically equivalent?

Tags: proof-verification, induction, peano-axioms

I want to prove the following theorem:

> **Theorem 1**: Let $a,b,c\in\mathbb{N}$, then $a+b\neq a$

using the following axiom

> **Axiom**: There exists a set $\mathbb{N}$ with an element $1 \in\mathbb{N}$ and a function $s: \mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ that satisfy the following three properties.
>
> 1. There is no n $\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $s(n)=1$.
> 2. The function $s$ is injective.
> 3. Let $G\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ be a set. Suppose $1 \in G$, and that if g $\in G$ then $s(g)\in G$. Then $G=\mathbb{N}$.

and theorem

> **Theorem 1**: There is a unique binary operation +: $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ that satisfies the following two properties for all n,m $\in\mathbb{N}$
>
> 1) $n+1=s(n)$
>
> 2) $n+s(m)=s(n+m)$

I have two proof ideas, and I do not know if they satisfy the "$g\in G\rightarrow s(g)\in G$" line of part 3 of the axiom.

My first idea was to consider a set $G=\{a\in\mathbb{N}:\forall b\in\mathbb{N}(a+b\neq a)\}$ and show that the contrapositve of $g\in G\rightarrow s(g)\in G$ is true, that is, $\neg(s(g)\in G)\rightarrow\neg(g\in G)$, but I do not know if changing the axiom like that is allowed.

My second idea was to show that $((g\in G)\land\neg(s(g)\in G))\rightarrow false$ which is shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1601944/induction-and-contradiction) to be logically eqivalent to $g\in G\rightarrow s(g)\in G$. Again, I do not know if its okay to change the logical structure of an axiom.

Comment: You're missing a definition of $+$ (or at least axioms that assert some properties of it).

Comment: Anyway, if you manage to prove $\forall g: s(g)\notin G\to g\notin G$ then you don't need to "change the axiom". Simply derive $\forall g:g\in G\to s(g)\in G$ from $\forall g:s(g)\notin G\to g\notin G$ by contraposition, and you're all set to use the official form of the axiom.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I did not think that would matter because I am only concerned with the logical structure of the proof (can I use the contrapositive instead of the premise given) and not so much with the details of the actual proof. I will add the definition of $+$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Am I allowed to derive the official form of the axiom from the contrapositive? Because I would not be using any theorems or definitions to do that, I would just be using a truth table?

Comment: You don't need to "derive the official form of the axiom" -- it's an axiom; you already have it. But you're certainly always allowed to derive $P\to Q$ from $\neg Q\to \neg P$, or to derive $\neg Q\to\neg P$ from $P\to Q$ -- that's what the two statements being equivalent means.

Comment: @HenningMakholm The reason I am ask this is becuase I was told some mathematicians do not like using the idea of a contrapositve, so I thought maybe it was not allowed. And to clairfy, all I have to do to is say the general statement is equivalent to the contrapositive by contraposition, then its okay?

Comment: The contrapositive of an implication is equivalent in classical logic. In intuitionistic logic they are not, but you should focus on learning one logic at a time, starting with classical (first-order) logic. Later once you've a good enough grasp of classical logic it is easy to learn about other logics. Almost all modern mathematics is done in classical logic, so feel free to use the equivalence.