# Find maximum value of $a$ such that the matrix has three linearly independent real eigenvectors .

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The maximum value of $a$ such that the matrix

$\begin{pmatrix} -3 & 0 & -2 \\ 1 & -1 & 0 \\0 & a & -2\end{pmatrix}$

has three linearly independent real eigenvectors .

Please give me a hint

Thanks

Comment: If a 3x3 matrix has three linearly independent eigenvectors, what does that tell you about the matrix?

Comment: That it has 3 distinct eigen values

Comment: True, but is there a more general property of the matrix as a whole that you can link to this?

Comment: @EHH That it is symmetric? Is it ?

Comment: Apologies I think my logic was wrong when giving that hint, I was thinking that it made the matrix invertible but I now don't think that's necessarilly the case.

Comment: @FrancisBegbie So what should be done. Which condition ?

Comment: @FrancisBegbie i have row reduced.Now what? Thanks'

Comment: But i have to find maximum value of a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** It was pointed out in the comments, that my [first attempt](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1609511/3) was incorrect, since the question asks about **real** eigenvectors. (I only checked whether there are independent eigenvectors, admitting the possibility that they might be complex.)

I have tried to suggest an alternative solution. I hope that somebody will come up with something more simple. (Either I have made a mistake somewhere, or the computation which we have to do would be rather complicated if we want solve the question by hand.)

---

We can start by calculating the [characteristic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial) $\chi_A(x)$?

$\chi_A(x)=\begin{bmatrix}  x+3 & 0 & 2 \\  -1 & x+1 & 0 \\   0 & -a & x+2 \end{bmatrix} =x^3+6x^2+11x+6+2a=(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)+2a$

[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=determinant+%5B%5Bt%2B3%2C0%2C2%5D%2C%5B-1%2Ct%2B1%2C0%5D%2C%5B0%2C-a%2Ct%2B2%5D%5D)

We can find situations for which this polynomial has real roots/distinct roots using the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#The_nature_of_the_roots) of the cubic polynomial.

[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=discriminant+x%5E3%2B6x%5E2%2B11x%2B6%2B2a)

Namely we get that for $a=\frac1{\sqrt {27}}$ there is a multiple real root. (This root can be found as the root of the derivative.) For larger $a$'s there are two complex roots and one real root. For smaller $a$'s there are three distinct real roots.

[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3%2B6x%5E2%2B11x%2B6%2B2%2Fsqrt%2827%29)

For three distinct real roots the situation is simple: [How to prove that eigenvectors from different eigenvalues are linearly independent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29371/how-to-prove-that-eigenvectors-from-different-eigenvalues-are-linearly-independe)

For $a=\frac1{\sqrt {27}}$ we cannot say just from the eigenvalues whether the matrix is diagonalizable or not. So now we can try to diagonalize this matrix for this particular value of $a$. (Or at least to find the dimension of the eigenspace for the multiple root.)

[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diagonalize+%5B%5B-3%2C0%2C-2%5D%2C%5B1%2C-1%2C0%5D%2C%5B0%2C1%2Fsqrt%2827%29%2C-2%5D%5D)

WolframAlpha says that the matrix is not diagonalizable. Which means that the given matrix have three real linearly independent eigenvectors only for $a<\frac1{\sqrt {27}}$.

Comment: We not only have to avoid repeated roots, we have to make sure all the roots are real.  That is what will set the upper limit on $a$.

Comment: D'oh! I have missed that the question asks about **real** eigenvectors. Now it makes more sense. (It seemed too easy.)

Comment: @RossMillikan Is there a straight way to do this question

Comment: @TaylorTed: Martin Sleziak has added it in.  For $a=0$ the curve drops below the $x$ axis.  As you increase $a$ it reaches a point where it just touches  If $a$ is any larger,two of the roots become complex.

Comment: @MartinSleziak:  $\LaTeX$ hint:  to get both of the digits of $\sqrt {27}$ under the square root bar, you need to put them in braces.  So \sqrt {27} instead of \sqrt 27 gives $\sqrt {27}$ instead of $\sqrt 27$