# Hermitian matrix linear algebra distinct eigenvalues problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a Hermetian matrix having all district eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_n$. If $X_1, X_2,\ldots X_n$ are corresponding eigenvectors then show that the $n\times n$ matrix $C$ whose $k^{th}$ column consists of the vector $X_k$ is nonsingular.

I need to show that matrix $C$ in the question (above or [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZN4a.jpg)) is non singular.

Comment: Hint: Vectors having pairwise distinct eigenvalues are linearly independent. What does this tell you about the (column) rank of your matrix?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29371/how-to-prove-that-eigenvectors-from-different-eigenvalues-are-linearly-independe

Comment: I found from other problems that Eigen vectors corresponding to two distinct  eigenvalues of hermitian matrix are mutually orthogonal. Then normalising the eigenvectors a unitary square matrix is formed which is non singular with nonzero determinant. (Is solving the  main question on similar lines all right?)