# Distinct eigenvalues implies $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is diagonalisable

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

Theorem:

> If an $n \times n$ matrix has n distinct eigenvalues then A is diagonalisable.

Proof:

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. Suppose A is not diagonalisable. 
Then, by definition, for a given $D \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ there exists no invertible matrix $P \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ such that $P^{-1}AP = D$.

Any hint(s) to assist me would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**  I would prefer to prove it directly.

Eigenvectors for distinct eigenvalues are linearly independent.   Thus we have a basis for $V$ consisting of eigenvectors.  Simply let $P$ be the matrix whose columns are the basis vectors.

> Then $P^{-1}AP=D$, where $D$ is diagonal,  and the entries on the diagonal are the eigenvalues.

Comment: don't you need symmetry for linear independent eigenvectors?

Comment: No.  See this:  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/29374

Comment: @ChrisCuster By construction, the j column of the matrix P is the j eigenvectors in the L.I set S of eigenvectors. Clearly, set S is the column space of P. 
I'd like to show that every column of P has a pivot position. Can you give me a hint on this?

Comment: Hmm.  Clearly the columns are independent,  as they are the elements of a basis.   To get pivots you would have to take the transpose and row-reduce,  say.

Comment: @ChrisCuster Satisfied.