# What is the appropriate way to find linearly independent column vectors in a square matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, python

I want to find linearly independent column vectors in a square matrix without using rref. In similar Stack Overflow questions, to find linearly independent columns in a square matrix, the recommended method is to use eigenvalue. If eigenvalue is zero, its corresponding eigenvector is linearly dependent but it is just relationship between eigenvector and eigenvalue. i seriously want to know which indices in a matrix are linearly independent.

thank you for your answering.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove that eigenvectors from different eigenvalues are linearly independent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29371/how-to-prove-that-eigenvectors-from-different-eigenvalues-are-linearly-independe)

Comment: in my cases, i  want to find a linearly independent column vectors by using eigenvalues. that is, in 4x4 matrices i want to decide which column vectors are independent.