# Rank 1 operator on an infinite dimensional vector space number of eigenvalues.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis

Does a rank 1 bounded operator from $\mathscr{K}:L^2([0,1])\to L^2([0,1])$ have at most 1 non-zero eigenvalue? The reason this is not obvious to me is that $L^2([0,1])$ is infinite dimensional. In general, is rank a bound on the number of eigenvalues?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, in general, this is true: the rank is an upper bound on the number of non-zero eigenvalues.

If we have a linear operator $T : X \to X$, where $X$ is not necessarily finite-dimensional, then saying $T$ has finite rank $n$ means that $\operatorname{Im} T$ is has finite dimension $n$. Note also that, if $v \in X$ is an eigenvector for eigenvalue $\lambda \neq 0$, then
$$v = \lambda^{-1}\lambda v = T(\lambda^{-1}v) \in \operatorname{Im} T.$$
Finally, as we always have, eigenvectors for distinct eigenvalues are linearly independent. The standard proof works in general, and does not require finite-dimensionality (you can find a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29371/how-to-prove-that-eigenvectors-from-different-eigenvalues-are-linearly-independe)). This means that we can only fit at most $n$ such eigenvalues into the $\operatorname{Im}(T)$ and still keep the dimension $n$.